# Finding difficulty in protractor automation for element inside ng-repeat having an order by condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I got a dropdown implemented using `ng-repeat` with an `orderBy` condition.

`ng-repeat="state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state'"`

I am trying to implement this as:

```
    //Get Array elements from States dropdown and select a state.

    browser.findElement(state).click(); //this is where we click on dropdown to make drop down items visible.

    browser.findElements(by.repeater('state in vm.states')).then(function (item1) {
            item1[2].click();
    });
```

Also observed adding condition included in `ng-repeat` in our locator is resulting in syntax error which I feel is expected. But I am stuck proceeding with selecting an item from dropdown because of this "order by" condition and looking for community's help in getting through this. Please let me know if more info is needed regarding this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can't understand what you want !? what is your target?

Comment: @Maher, target is to select an item from the drop down. I have successfully performed automation on drop down items before which had only ng-repeat with no orderBy in it. But in this case, we have ng-repeat implemented along with orderBy to display sorted list.This is making it difficult for me to find drop down items and was looking for expert help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, better to use the "default" ElementFinder syntax of Protractor:
which is for example element(by.repeater('state in vm.states'));,

In your case

//Page object class

```
 this.state = element.all(by.repeater('state in vm.states''));

     this.getState = function () {
        return this.state.get(2).click;
      };
```

// call you page class in spec file

```
page.getState();
```